# store and retrieve dictionary data from hiredis (a Redis client in C programming)

Tags: hiredis

I try to use hiredis (a Redis client written in C), to send and retrieve the dictionary data, from the Redis server.

I can send/receive simple data by using hiredis APIs. I can also retrieve and send the dictionary data using redis-py (a Redis client written in Python). However, I can't find the APIs for dictionary data types in hiredis.

My data is like: 
data = {2: {"load":2.5, "temp":30 } }

Anyone please give some helps? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem fixed. I wrapped up the dictionary into a string.